# how can without refreshing pull data with ajax in django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I can post with ajax, but when I want to pull data without refreshing the page, I can only do it 2 times, then the button loses its function.

```
 <div>
                          <input type="hidden" name="producecode" class="pcode" value="{{per.produceCode}}" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="useremail" class="uponequantity" value="{{user.username}}" />
                          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary upoq"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
```

and jquery

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/uponequantity/",
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
    data: {
    "producecode":$(this).parent().find(".pcode").val(),
    "useremail":$(".uponequantity").val(),
  },
    success: function() {
      window.location.assign('/basket/'+"?b="+$(".uponequantity").val());
    }

    
});
/*$.ajax({
              url:'/baskett/'+"?b="+$(".uponequantity").val(),
              headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
              type:'POST',
              success:function(result){
                  $('.basket').html(result);
      }
      });

*/

})
```

Comment: `$(".pcode").val()` references `.pcode`, but I think it should be `.pdcode` instead right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another line to reference your second input same as the first.

```
$(".up").click(function(){
  $(".prdtd").find("input:first-  child").attr("value"); 
  $(".pcode").val()
  $(".uponequantity").val()//<-- new line for the second hidden value
}
```

**-----------------------------------------**
**Update:**
**-----------------------------------------**

OP has multiple buttons with the same class each in it's own div and wants to access the values within each div.

So, first off you need to change "*pcode*" from an id to class in order to get all instances. (*id* is for unique instances)

After that you need to be able to get the "*pcode*" & "*uponequantity*" that are associated with that button and one way of doing that is:

```
$(".up").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".pcode").val()
  $(this).parent().find(".uponequantity").val()
}
```

Simply put, the `this` keyword references the clicked button.
You then get the direct parent element which would have the button and the hidden values as children.
Finally you get each specific child through the `find` command and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Thank you, but the part I'm having trouble with is the hidden input, whose name is produce code.

Comment: @Kazım you mentioned that "it only takes the first value", what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Kazım It would be better if you could provide your entire code so that we may help better.

Comment: I share the full code

Comment: @Kazım I read the post you deleted, and I understood what you want. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank You @Gabriel I updated my ask with Ari's advice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to get the value of both inputs in your callback.

It seems like you misspelt `pdcode` in your JavaScript.

Does the below code snippet help?

```js
$(".up").click(function() {
  const value1 = $(".pdcode").val();
  const value2 = $(".uponequantity").val();
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to click different button pdcode return different value but i click different button pdcode return one value

Comment: It would be much easier if you could add more of your code

Comment: I share the full code